# simple form fields save as nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, simple-form

I have a model Project and a simple_form form so the User model can register a project.

I have two fields that doesn't work and return NIL:

- project_type
- used_techno

Here is my simple_form form :

```
<%= simple_form_for(@project) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :name, label: "What's the name of this project ?"%>
    <%= f.input :project_type, 
                label: "What type is this project ?",
                collection: ['blog', 'Showcase', 'market place', 'e-commerce', 'social network' ],
                :multiple => true, 
                :as => :check_boxes, 
                required: false, 
                include_blank: false %>
    <%= f.input :used_techno, 
                collection: ['RoR', 'HTML5', 'SCSS', 'JavaScript' ], 
                :multiple => true, 
                :as => :check_boxes, 
                required: false, 
                include_blank: false %>
    <%= f.input :description, placeholder: "Max 140 characteres"%>
    <%= f.input :date_of_publication %>
    <%= f.input :link, placeholder: "Copy/Past a link of your work in this field"%>
    <%= f.input :image, as: :file %>
  </div>
   <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.button :submit, "NEW PROJECT", class:"submitButton" %>
     </div>
   <% end %>
```

Here is my DB :

```
create_table "projects", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "used_techno"
    t.string "project_type"
    t.text "description"
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.date "date_of_publication"
    t.string "link"
    t.string "image"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_projects_on_user_id"
  end
```

I have tried to put the form fields as "simple" string fields like this :

```
<%= f.input :project_type, label: "What type is this project ?"
```

But it keep returning NIL values.

Other fields are working perfectly well.

Here is the method create, new and the params from the project_controller.rb :

```
 def new
    @project = Project.new
  end

  def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)
    @project.user=current_user
    @project.save!
    redirect_to userprojects_projects_path
  end
 private

    def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:name, :project_type, :description, :date_of_publication, :used_techno, :link, :user_id, :image)
    end
end
```

Here is my Project.rb file, I had to comment the validates refering to project_type and used_techno otherwise it returns an error message saying that these fields are requiered.

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  # validates :project_type, presence: true
  validates :description, length: { maximum: 140 }
  # validates :used_techno, presence: true
  validates :link, presence: true, uniqueness: true

  has_one_attached :image

  def project_image
    if image.attached?
      image.key
    else
      "default_profile_pic_xl837y"
    end
  end

end
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: What does your controller method look like? What does the log file entry for a POST request look like?

Comment: I just edited the post with the controller and Post file

Comment: I dont know if this plays a role here but 'type' is a reserved keyword, so i tend to avoid it, secondly i suggest you checkout the params: if you are passing checkboxes, you will get an array (of all the values you checked), so your controller strong params need to expect an array too.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it didn't work when you tried to use a simple string input, but let's work with what you're really trying to accomplish.

You're trying to send an array of strings (collection), but project_type and used_techno only take one string. What you want is that a project can have many types and many technos, right? I would then create tables to hold these associations, instead of just providing an array of strings for your collections. After that you can look up [simple form's documentation about associations](https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form#associations), there's a relevant example with user roles. Don't forget that you'll also need to permit these params as arrays in your controller (see [strong params doc](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#permitted-scalar-values)).

There is also a way to define `array: true` when you create your projects table (see [active record doc](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#array)), seems pretty easy to use, but I personally never did. Depends what you plan to do with those project types and used technos in your app.